# How do I make iOS Charts LineChartView show as a spline (smooth line chart)?

Tags: ios, swift, ios-charts

I'm new to iOS Charts, but I've figured out how to do many things with it.  One thing I can't figure out (or find anywhere) is how to show the LineChartView as a spline instead of distinct lines to each data point.  I want it to be smooth and flowing, not jagged.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! What code do you already have? Have you tried any code and found it not working?

Comment: Can you please put image here, so we can understand exact requirement.

Answer (score 31):

Set the `mode` in the `LineChartDataSet`:

```
let dataSet = LineChartDataSet(values: entries, label: "Foo")
dataSet.mode = .cubicBezier
```

Comment: can we invert this?

Comment: How to remove data set label ?

Comment: @KiritVaghela :

dataSet.drawValuesEnabled = false